# Is it possible to modify TStringField class (with new property)

Tags: delphi, unicode-string, delphi-11-alexandria, tstringfield

Using Delphi 11.3 and an Oracle DB using UniDac, I have the problem that there are many old apps (written in Cobol) which do not support Unicode, so the data for text fields is stored as Ansi text using the (Windows) client's codepage (125x). I have to replace them step by step and use "new" tables where I store the data in Unicode (UTF-16).

As long as the old apps are still in use, I have to "translate" the Ansi strings into UTF (and back for writing).

I have written 2 functions:
`function AnsiToUTF(Value: AnsiString; codepage: word): string;`
and
`function UTFToAnsi(Value: string; codepage word): AnsiString`
which are working.

I searched this forum and it seems to be possible to make changes to the `TStringField` class, but I have no experience in doing so.

It would be great if I could apply a new property `AsUTF` to the `TStringField` class with my 2 functions embedded in `SetAsUTF()` and `GetAsUTF()` to that I can call them in any data-aware component using `TFields`. For example:

`MyString := UniQuery1.FieldByName('TEXT').AsUTF(1252);`
and
`UniQuery1.FieldByName('TEXT').AsUTF(1252) := MyString;`

Would that be possible (or is there a better solution)?

#EDIT: I was told to give a reproducible example for it, so here it is:

```
unit UTFStringField;

TUTFStringField = class(TWideStringField)
protected
  procedure SetAsUTF(UTF: string; Codepage: word);
  function GetAsUTF(Codepage: word): string;
  constructor Create; override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
public
  function UTFToAnsi(txt: string; GCodePage: word): Ansistring;
  function AnsiToUTF(txt: Ansistring; GCodepage: word): string;
end;

implementation

procedure TUTFStringField.SetAsUTF(UTF: string; Codepage: word);
begin
  SetAsAnsiString(UTFToAnsi(UTF,Codepage));
end;

function TUTFStringField.GetAsUTF(CodePage: word): string;
begin
  Result := AnsiToUTF(GetAsAnsiString,CodePage);
end;

constructor TUTFStringField.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  DefaultFieldClasses[ftWideString] := TUTFStringField;
end;

destructor TUTFStringField.Destroy;
begin
  DefaultFieldClasses[ftWideString] := TWideStringField;
  inherited destroy;
end;

function TUTFStringField.AnsiToUTF(txt: Ansistring; GCodepage:     word): string;
var
  NewStr: string;
  OldChar: AnsiChar;
  NewChar: Char;
  i: integer;
begin
  NewStr := '';
  case GCodepage of
  1250: begin
        for i := 1 to Length(txt) do
          begin
            OldChar := txt[i];
            NewChar := Char(OldChar);
            case Ord(OldChar) of
            $80: NewChar := Char($20AC); // #EURO SIGN
            $82: NewChar := Char($201A); // #SINGLE LOW-9         
            $84: NewChar := Char($201E); // #DOUBLE LOW-9 
            $85: NewChar := Char($2026); // #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
            ....
            end;
            NewStr := NewStr + NewChar;
          end;
        end;
  1251: begin
          for i := 1 to Length(txt) do
          begin
            OldChar := AnsiChar(txt[i]);
            NewChar := Char(OldChar);
            case Ord(OldChar) of
            $80: NewChar := Char($0402); // #CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER   
            $81: NewChar := Char($0403); // #CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER 
            $82: NewChar := Char($201A); // #SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION      
            ...
           end;
            NewStr := NewStr + NewChar;
          end;
        end;
  end;
  Result := NewStr;
end;

function TUTFStringField.UTFToAnsi(txt: string; GCodepage: word):    Ansistring;
var
  NewStr: Ansistring;
  OldChar: Char;
  NewChar: AnsiChar;
  i: integer;
begin

  NewStr := '';

  case GCodepage of
  1250: begin
          for i := 1 to Length(txt) do
          begin
            OldChar := Copy(txt,i,1);
            NewChar := AnsiChar(OldChar);
            case Ord(OldChar) of
            $20AC: NewChar := AnsiChar($80);
            $201A: NewChar := AnsiChar($82);
            $201E: NewChar := AnsiChar($84); // DOUBLE LOW-9 
            $2026: NewChar := AnsiChar($85); // HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
            $2020: NewChar := AnsiChar($86); // DAGGER
            ....
            end;
            NewStr := NewStr + NewChar;
          end;
        end;
  1251: begin
          for i := 1 to Length(txt) do
          begin
            OldChar := Char(txt[i]);
            NewChar := AnsiChar(OldChar);
            case Ord(OldChar) of
            $0402: NewChar := AnsiChar($80); //  CYRILLIC CAPITAL 
            $0403: NewChar := AnsiChar($81); //  CYRILLIC CAPITAL 
            $201A: NewChar := AnsiChar($82); //  SINGLE LOW-9 
            $0453: NewChar := AnsiChar($83); //  CYRILLIC SMALL 
            $201E: NewChar := AnsiChar($84); //  DOUBLE LOW-9 
            end;
            NewStr := NewStr + NewChar;
          end;
        end;
  end;

interface

  RegisterClass(TUTFStringField);

end.
```

Surely the constructor / destructor is wrong, but I have no idea, how and where to introduce my new `TUTFStringField` class, so that it is always used in the moment, for example when I drop an UniQuery component on my form.

Oh, and by the way: I set `"UniCode"` in the Oracle Uni provider to true, as my new apps should use Unicode as default (the database charset is UTF-16).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You could try to create a helper for ``TStringField`` with your methods added

Comment: I am not a delphi professionel - could you please give me a hint how to do it?

Comment: @user1304759 read [Class and Record Helpers (Delphi)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, your translation functions are unnecessary. The RTL has its own ways of converting to/from Ansi strings with codepages, such as `System.LocaleCharsFromUnicode()` and `System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars()`, or `SysUtils.TEncoding`, or `RawByteString` with `System.SetCodePage()`.

You should use the built-in functionality instead of rolling your own. especially since you are not handling UTF-16 surrogates, whereas the RTL will.

Try something more like this instead:

```
unit UTFStringField;

interface

uses
  Data.DB;

type
  TUTFStringField = helper class for TField
  public
    procedure SetAsUTF(const UTF: string; Codepage: Word);
    function GetAsUTF(Codepage: Word): string;
  end;

implementation

procedure TUTFStringField.SetAsUTF(const UTF: string; Codepage: Word);
var
  NewStr: AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(NewStr, LocaleCharsFromUnicode(Codepage, 0, PChar(UTF), Length(UTF), nil, 0, nil, nil));
  LocaleCharsFromUnicode(Codepage, 0, PChar(UTF), Length(UTF), PAnsiChar(NewStr), Length(NewStr), nil, nil);
  SetCodePage(PRawByteString(@NewStr)^, Codepage, False);

  { alternatively:
  var enc: TEncoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(Codepage);
  try
    SetLength(NewStr, enc.GetByteCount(UTF));
    enc.GetBytes(PChar(UTF), Length(UTF), PByte(PAnsiChar(NewStr)), Length(NewStr));
  finally
    enc.Free;
  end;
  SetCodePage(PRawByteString(@NewStr)^, Codepage, False);
  }

  { alternatively:
  var raw: RawByteString := PRawByteString(@UTF)^;
  SetCodePage(raw, Codepage, True);
  NewStr := PAnsiString(@raw)^;
  }

  Self.AsAnsiString := NewStr;
end;

function TUTFStringField.GetAsUTF(Codepage: Word): string;
var
  txt: AnsiString;
begin
  txt := Self.AsAnsiString;

  SetLength(Result, UnicodeFromLocaleChars(Codepage, 0, PAnsiChar(txt), Length(txt), nil, 0));
  UnicodeFromLocaleChars(Codepage, 0, PAnsiChar(txt), Length(txt), PWideChar(Result), Length(Result));

  { alternatively:
  var enc: TEncoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(Codepage);
  try
    SetLength(Result, enc.GetCharCount(PByte(PAnsiChar(txt)), Length(txt)));
    enc.GetChars(PByte(PAnsiChar(txt)), Length(txt), PChar(Result), Length(Result));
  finally
    enc.Free;
  end;
  }

  { alternatively:
  SetCodePage(PRawByteString(@txt)^, Codepage, False);
  Result := string(txt);
  }
end;

end.
```

And then, you can call them like this (just make sure `UTFStringField` is in the `uses` clause):

```
MyString := UniQuery1.FieldByName('TEXT').GetAsUTF(1252);
```

```
UniQuery1.FieldByName('TEXT').SetAsUTF(MyString, 1252);
```